# How to get Salesforce Fields from SpringCM Workflow?

Tags: c#, adobe, docusignapi

I am creating case in workflow so that each time signatures done by all parties, it automatically create case. But i want to know, How to get Salesforce fields and its value in SpringCM? The case which i am going to create have lookup fields(Account, Contact).

The step which i have used is "Add Salesforce Task".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the SF 18 digit unique Ids from the URL. Add them as hidden fields on the Doc Launcher form, that way your workflow can leverage the id’s in the process for Case creation.

Make sure you are using Salesforce API names, if you are not it will not populate for you (same as dataloader)